# How to use openpyxl to find a cell with a specific value?

Tags: python, excel

I have many Excel files, and I want to get the cell reference of the cell, for each file containing `Phone Number`.

The problem is, the position of this cell reference changes with each file.

I'm able to load the workbook but stuck after

```py
from openpyxl import *
wb = load_workbook('Workbook', data_only=True)
wb_sheet = wb['Sheet1']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code

Comment: @James i can only open the workbook, cannot find the dynamic value reference

Comment: It would be nice to see data sample (Excel file with cell for Phone Number) and at least single attempt of yours to get the data by code.